# How to build subquery for this

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have one table having field viz.

```
id,is_public,added_by,is_delete
```

Scenario possiblities :

current user can see records having :

1. **`added_by admin = 0 OR own id`**
2. **`added_by another user AND is_public = 1`**
3. `**is_deleted=0**`

**`current user's and admin's record is_public='0'`** record must be shown

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/435b2d/3)

my query :

```
SELECT * FROM tblname 
WHERE 
is_delete='0' 
AND (added_by='0' OR added_by='15') //ex. current user id = 15
AND is_public='1'
```

but this query is not giving another user's `is_public='1'` record

Kindly help

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/435b2d/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some more and got success, thank you all for support :)

```
SELECT * FROM tblname 
WHERE 
is_delete = '0' AND 
( user_id = '0' OR user_id = '15' OR is_public = '1' )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use OR operator into your select:

```
SELECT * FROM tblname 
WHERE 
is_delete='0' AND (
   (added_by='0' OR added_by='15') //ex. current user id = 15
   OR is_public='1'
)
```

If user should see any own records which is deleted or not then you can use this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM tblname 
WHERE 
added_by='15' //ex. current user id = 15
OR (
   is_delete='0' AND (added_by='0' OR is_public='1')
);
```

Comment: and after removing OR inside bracket, its not showing current users record having `is_public=0`

Comment: sorry, I forgot to remove excess OR while replace it with first AND

Comment: this record is_public but also is_deleted. Is current user should see own deleted records?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable support, kindly find my answer, solved query :)

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
SELECT * FROM tblname 
WHERE 
is_delete='0' AND (
(added_by='0' OR added_by='15') //ex. current user id = 15
OR is_public='1')
```

This way you show only undleted posts that are : from the same user or public

Update:
If you want the show current users deleted posts as well (so all posts by users 0 / 14, and only public and not deleted posts by other users:

```
SELECT * FROM temp 
WHERE 
(
   (user_id='0' OR user_id='15') OR
   (is_delete='0' AND  is_public='1')
)
```

Comment: `current user's is_public='0'` record must be shown

Comment: it is: the where says "bytheuser OR public"

Comment: its not showing, current user's not publically record means having `is_public='0'`

Comment: @Sagar: lets say you have a post where added_by=15, is_public=0 and is_delete=0. In that case the where will return true : T AND ( (F OR T) OR F) = T AND ( T OR F) = T AND T = T

Comment: yes! correct! and other user should only have `is_public='1'`

Comment: @Sagar: if you have a post where added_by=16, is_public=0 and is_delete=0. In that case the where will return false : T AND ( (F OR F) OR F) = T AND ( F OR F) = T AND F = . Isn't that the desired behaviour?

Comment: no! its only checking `is_public='1'` and even own result having '0'

Comment: hello, still your last updated query giving deleted values also, Thank you for your valuable support, kindly find my answer, solved query :)

Comment: in the sql fidle which line is displayed and shouldn't be ?